# laravel - reset password for multiple accounts

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am using Laravel's "reset password".

There is something particular in our architecture: several accounts can have the same email address, the login is the unique key.
I would like to change the password reset controller so that, in password reset view:
- if the user put its email, the password is set for all accounts with this email (should I do it in a middleware? now only a random account is set, the first one I guess)
- if the user put its login, we change the password of its login only

Do you think this is possible? (for new accounts it will be impossible to create a new account with an existing email, but now we have about 8000 users with double email accounts, so this cannot be changed unfortunately).
thanks a lot in advance for your advices!

here is my code and I don't know where to start

[EDIT]

Here is my code after Mostakim Billah's suggestion:
I rewrote the existing resetPassword et reset function (let them as they were) and added the //HERE part

```
public function reset(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate($this->rules(), $this->validationErrorMessages());

        $response = $this->broker()->reset(
            $this->credentials($request), function ($user, $password) {
                $this->resetPassword($user, $password);
            }
        );

        return $response == Password::PASSWORD_RESET
                    ? $this->sendResetResponse($request, $response)
                    : $this->sendResetFailedResponse($request, $response);
    }

    protected function resetPassword($user, $password)
    {
        $user->password = Hash::make($password);

        $user->setRememberToken(Str::random(60));

        $user->save();

            // HERE: set passwords for other users with the same email
            **User::where('email', $user->email)
            ->where('login', '!=', $user->login)
            ->where('password', null)
            ->update(['password' => Hash::make($password)]);**

        event(new PasswordReset($user));

        $this->guard()->login($user);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override `reset` method(which is in `ResetsPasswords` trait) in `ResetPasswordController` class and do whatever you want in this method.

Comment: Thanks! I tried and edited my answer, and will test it right now